# PreferenceScreen not being restored on orientation change

Tags: android

I had the following (minor but nagging!) problem: I've got a `PreferenceActivity` with a XML preference hierarchy definition with "sub `PreferenceScreens`", i. e. several `PreferenceScreens` under the top level `PreferenceScreen`, and when the user clicks them, a sub hierarchy of other preferences is being displayed.

If I have displayed such a **sub** `PreferenceScreen` and the orientation is being changed from portrait to landscape or vice versa, the **main** `PreferenceScreen` is displayed afterwards. Which means: The preference hierarchy state was not being restored properly. I would expect the **sub** `PreferenceScreen` to be displayed after the orientation change, just as before the orientation change.

Now I found out that the problem can be solved by assigning any random key (e. g. "dummy") to the sub `PreferenceScreen`. Which does not make any sense! Why would a `PreferenceScreen` ever need a key (except as a workaround for the above problem)?

My actual question: Is this behaviour a bug in the framework class(es)? If not: Can someone explain me how that makes sense?

My example code:

HelloAndroid.java:

```
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button view = new Button(this);
        view.setText("Start Preference");
        final Context ctx = this;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ctx, HelloPreferenceActivity.class));
            }
        });
        this.setContentView(view);
    }
```

HelloPreferenceActivity.java:

```
public class HelloPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

preference.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="examplePref"
        android:title="ExamplePref">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="SubScreen..."
        android:key="dummy"> <!-- works with, does not work without this key -->
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="exPrefSubScreen"
            android:title="ExPrefSubScreen">
        </CheckBoxPreference>
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, the state of `Preference` is associated with its key. If Preference has no key then it will not be able to save/restore its state.

The similar behavior can be found in views withing layouts. If view has no `id` specified for it, it will not be able to restore state after configuration change.

And to back my words up, here is an example of how `Preference` [saves its state](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/preference/Preference.java&q=onRestoreInstanceState%20preference&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git&d=4&l=1494):

```
void dispatchSaveInstanceState(Bundle container) {
    if (hasKey()) {
        mBaseMethodCalled = false;
        Parcelable state = onSaveInstanceState();
        if (!mBaseMethodCalled) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Derived class did not call super.onSaveInstanceState()");
        }
        if (state != null) {
            container.putParcelable(mKey, state);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how `Preference` tries to [restore its state](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/preference/Preference.java&q=onRestoreInstanceState%20preference&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git&d=4&l=1547):

```
void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(Bundle container) {
    if (hasKey()) {
        Parcelable state = container.getParcelable(mKey);
        if (state != null) {
            mBaseMethodCalled = false;
            onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            if (!mBaseMethodCalled) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Derived class did not call super.onRestoreInstanceState()");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi inazaruk, thank you for the explanation. Okay, I understand that the "key" has a similar meaning for preferences (including PreferenceScreens) as the "ID" for views. Knowing that, I will always take care from now on to assign unique keys to **every** preference element in the preference hierarchy tree. But still, I think they could have solved it better. Because when creating a view hierarchy (i. e. layout) using the SDK, a unique ID is assigned to every view automatically. Whereas for a preference hierarchy, you obviously have to care about that yourself. Cheers, Nemax

Comment: No, views don't have ids automatically generated. If you do not add `android:id="@+id/myViewId"` to view in layout or call `setId()`, then your view will not save/restore data. The only thing that is generated is integer value for id, not the id itself.

Comment: What I meant was that if you use the Eclipse SDK and the integrated layout editor, entries e. g. "@+id/radioButton1" are automatically being generated. That's the first thing. The second thing is that you CAN define IDs which are always unique by writing "@+id/something", the system will generate fully unique IDs then. For preference elements, both is not possible. The SDK won't generate IDs for you, and you cannot define unique IDs by specifying something similar to "+id/somePreference". You have to fully take care of it yourself (which is feasible but not as convenient as for views...).

Comment: Yes, from that point of view, your are right. I'm not even sure why they didn't introduce similar id scheme for preferences. This is actually a good feature request.